# How does reRender work in VisualForce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two fields in my SalesForce page.

1. Site Field (newReq.Site__c)
2. Requisition (newReq.Requisition_Type__c)

Based on my Requisition type, I want my site field to be visible and hidden. Here are the *conditions* on when the site field should be seen and when not.

**Condition 1**: When the user selects Requisition Type: "XYZ" I want site field to be hidden.

**Condition 2**:  When the user selects anything other than XYZ then I want to show the site field again.

**My 1st question**:  Now I am confused here. As in, what to use when. My **Requsition** field should be declared as reRender (code 1) or  as rendered (code 2).

**Secondly**, So when I use **reRender** in my VisualForce page, do I need to add any code in my Controller ?

This is the code which I am trying to use:

**Code 1**

```
<apex:inputField id="reqType" styleClass="reqLineType" html-class="requist" 
value="{!newReq.Requisition_Type__c}"/> 
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="siteMaterial"/>
```

**Code 2**

```
<apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!bRenderThePanel}">
<apex:inputField value="{!newReq.Site__c}"  id="siteName" html-class="hideSite"/> 
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can avoid the `action=` attribute on the `apex:actionSupport` as well as the action method and code your controller property as follows:

```
public Boolean getBRenderThePanel() {return newReq.requisition_type__c != 'XYZ';}
```

Note that although the VF page refers to

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!bRenderThePanel}">
```

this resolves itself to the method `getBRenderThePanel` at compile time

When `action` is not included on actionSupport, the page will simply refresh after any changed values are sent to the controller.  Hence, since the value of `newReq.requisition_type__c` is sent to the controller by actionSupport, when the page refreshes, the request to `getBRenderThePanel` is made which has the current value of requisition_type__c so it can return the proper true/false value.

Comment: or `public Boolean getbRenderThePanel() { return newReq.requisition_type__c != 'XYZ'; }`; the setter really isn't necessary, since it will never be used.

Comment: you are of course, correct -- I fixed my answer - I had blindly copied my usual pattern for VF controller properties which was overkill in this use case

Comment: What you have doesn't work.  I don't get why @sfdcfox wouldn't just answer the question, since he seems to have to best solution.   You either need to make it a getter, or change the property to a function like fox suggested.

Comment: yikes - I didn't fix up the code correctly - missing the `()`. Thanks; now changed